# RxJS: forkJoin delay seems not working on more than 1 call

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9

i have two http call and i need tho delay the seconde call or wait too the first to complete and i added a delay but the second call executes always first.

ngOnInit

```
 forkJoin({
      getProductDetails:  this.getProductDetails(),
      getRelatedProducts: this.getRelatedProducts().pipe(delay(1000)) }).subscribe(res => {
        this.productDetailsData = res.getProductDetails;
        this.productsRelated = res.getRelatedProducts;
      }, err =>{
        // this.loader.hide();
      });
  }
```

getProductDetails

```
 getProductDetails(): Observable < any > {

    var queryString = `?productId=${this.productId}`;

    return this.marketCommunication.productDetails(queryString)
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          this.productCategoryId = res.productCategoryId

          return res
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          throw err;
        })
      )

  }
```

getRelatedProducts

```
getRelatedProducts(): Observable < any > {

    console.log( this.productCategoryId) // -> returns null

    var queryString = `?productCategoryId=${this.productCategoryId}&take=${4}&skip=${2}`;

    return this.marketCommunication.publishedProductsByFilters(queryString)
      .pipe(
       map((res) => {
          return res
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          throw err;
        })
      )


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use switchMap instead to ensure that they executed one after another:

```js
this.getProductDetails().pipe(
  // now we have result of the first request and executing 2nd one.
  switchMap(getProductDetails => this.getRelatedProducts().pipe(

    // merging results together.
    map(getRelatedProducts => ({
      getProductDetails,
      getRelatedProducts,
    })),
  )),
).subscribe(res => {
  this.productDetailsData = res.getProductDetails;
  this.productsRelated = res.getRelatedProducts;
});
```